# Text into image always grey

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to put on an image with transparent background a text with color. I put text into image but the font color is always grey

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Base-0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Save the transparency channel alpha


font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (300,500)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = [255, 0, 0]
lineType               = 1



gray_layer = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Duplicate the grayscale image to mimic the BGR image and finally add the transparency
*_, alpha = cv2.split(img)
dst = cv2.merge((gray_layer, gray_layer, gray_layer, alpha))

cv2.putText(dst,'Hello', 
    bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
    font, 
    fontScale,
    fontColor,
    lineType)

hsv=cv2.cvtColor(dst,0)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", hsv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an RGB color for your font and applying it to an RGBA colorspace. I would guess that cv2 is assuming the fourth (alpha) value to therefore be 0, making your text transparent. Update your font color to be:

```
fontColor              = [255, 0, 0, 255]
```